# Google c style settings for gnu indent?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, indentation

I am using google c indent style for Emacs ([google-c-style.el](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/google-c-style.el)) and Vim([google.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2636)).

But since I have some existing code that is not this style and I hope I can change it. I find there is a tool called GNU indent that can do such thing automatically and it provides some common style settings on [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_node/indent_4.html), however there is no for Google c indent style. SO is there equivalent for it as well?

(I tried the Linux and Berkley style and feel that they are by no means satisfactory for me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A brief reading of the google coding style shows that it is mostly K&R coding style, except with 2 space indentation (including case statements), 80 column lines, and no tabs. So, the following options should accomplish that:

```
-kr -ci2 -cli2 -i2 -l80 -nut
```

Start with that. You may have to tweak the resulting code. C++ support, in particular, is weak for `indent`.

Legend:

- `-kr`: K&R style
- `-ci2`: Continuation indent, the lines following the first line of a multi-line code statement get indented by 2 spaces
- `-cli2`: Case label indent, `case` labels are indented 2 spaces in from the `switch`
- `-i2`: Indentation, 2 spaces
- `-l80`: Length, 80 columns
- `-nut`: No tabs

As an alternative, you may consider [executing `emacs` in batch mode to apply indentation](http://www.cslab.pepperdine.edu/warford/BatchIndentationEmacs.html) on your code for you. Briefly:

Create a file called `emacs-format-file` with the contents:

```
(defun emacs-format-function ()
   "Format the whole buffer."
   (c-set-style "Google")
   (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
   (untabify (point-min) (point-max))
   (save-buffer))
```

Execute the following command from the shell:

```
emacs -batch your_source_file.c \
    -l emacs-format-file -f emacs-format-function
```

Comment: Seems that there are some flaws with GNU indent since I found that it works poorly with C++ template.

Comment: Yes, I noted the C++ support is weak for indent. But, I provided an alternative using `emacs` in batch mode.

Comment: I see. But Emacs built-in functions cannot generate whitespace, which is a bit frustrating; and Emacs would also do some minor changes when `GNU indent` has been applied(I guess it is the problem of the latter).

Comment: If you mean use spaces instead of tabs, add `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)` to your `c-mode-hook`.

Comment: By saying whitespace I include blank, tab and line-break. What I mean is that Emacs built-in function cannot insert those to format the code exactly(For instance, I hope there is a line-break among the function definition and its body, or I hope there is a blank between characters and closed brackets, GNU indent works but in Emacs/Vim there is no good way.)

Answer (score 13):

For the record, there is an alternate solution for those who are interested in Clang and LLVM.

[**clang-format**](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) definitely can help format existing source code easily and efficiently. It has *explicit* builtin support for 5 format, namely `LLVM`(default), `Google`, `Chromium`, `Mozilla`, `WebKit`.

The simples way to format a file with Google style is:

```
clang-format -style=Google -i filename
```

Where `-i` means inplace modification, you may try without this option to preview the changes.

To batch format existing C/C++ code we can simply use the command like:

```
find . -name "*.cc" | xargs clang-format -style=Google -i
```

Apart from the listed 5 formats, there are *actually* other styles like `GNU`(added on [revision 197138](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Format/Format.h?revision=197138&view=markup); it's a pity that the document is not synced).

Note that clang-format accepts rc like files named **.clang-format** or **_clang-format** in a project, the simplest way to add such a configuration file(as said in clang-format's official tutorial page) is to dump the configuration of an existing format like:

```
clang-format -style=Google -dump-config >.clang-format
```

Also you might also use `BasedOnStyle` option so a configuration file might look like:

```
---
BasedOnStyle:  Chromium
PointerBindsToType: false
ObjCSpaceAfterProperty: true
...
```

Use *.clang-format* or *_clang-format* as keywords to search on Github and there are other samples; or you might refer to [this site](http://clangformat.com/) to help build one.

There are also integrations for IDEs/Editors such as Visual Studio(in directory [clang-format-vs](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format-vs/)), Sublime, Emacs, Vim(all in directory [clang-format](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/)).

Another 3 tips:

1. For Emacs integration(`clang-format.el`), personally I think it's better to bind key for `clang-format-buffer` rather than `clang-format-region`.
2. For Mac OSX homebrew installation, use `brew install --with-clang, --with-lld, --with-python --HEAD      llvm` can get `clang-format` support and its integration files are in `$(brew --cache)/llvm--clang--svn-HEAD/tools/clang-format`(bonus: there is even a `git-clang-format` there!!).
3. There are other *fabulous* tools inside [**clang-extra-tools**](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/clang-tools-extra/trunk/) such as `clang-modernize`(which is used to "automatically convert C++ code written against old standards to use features of the newest C++ standard where appropriate"), really worthy of having a try!